# React js | Jodit editor table merge not working after production build

Tags: reactjs, jodit

After building production build (npm run build), table merge icon is not working but its working during development (npm start).

Can some one please help? Please find version of jodit and jodit react

**jodit**

```
jodit = 3.2.60
```

**jodit react**

```
 jodit-react =  1.0.26
```